# What can I do with => PATH/TO/REPOSITORY folder?

Tags: github, path, repository, git-clone, diskspace

I have just found the folder REPOSITORY in my local disk with the path:

> C:\PATH\TO\REPOSITORY

It is huge (4GB), considering the few repositories I have and I don't have many that I have cloned.

Besides, the files that are inside are completely unknown by me like:

- notocjksc.tar (200.000 KB)
- pst-geo.tar (139.567 KB)
- cbgreek.tar
- biber-darwin-x86_64.tar

To name a few, actually I have more than 4000 files...

So I have no idea what those files are there for, as well as whether or not I could delete them, or some of them, to free some space from my disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as well as whether or not I could delete them, or some of them, to free some space from my disk.

If you do not need those files, you can delete them, but it will impact only the local disk, not the remote repository.

I would check in each repository the remote URL

```
 git remote -v
```

And check on the remote side if the same huge files were pushed or not.
Then you would need to decide if those files should stay in those remote repositories or not.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that. Why are those files there though?  I have also read that this folder is the same as if you had cloned a repository from some remote hosting site; it just so happens that the origin is located on your local disk. However, is it completely necessary? Why am I cloning twice the repository then? I only want to have "origin" from github not in my local path/to/repository folder and only work with the cloned repo in my workspace folder for VScode. I don't understand why when I clone the repos through VScode it sends it there as well...

Comment: @Julio A git status will show you if those files are purely local, or if they are tracked. More generally, the idea of a distributed version control system is to clone locally a remote repository. In your case, if you do not have local development, you could simply remove everything, then clone manually only the repository you want to work on.

Comment: Sorry but I find it difficult to follow you.. bear with me please. What I do is just to clone my own repos from my git hub and then work locally and push changes. I still have no idea why that path/to/repo folder is create, what those unknown huge files are and the importance of that. Also, how can I get the git status? Thanks

Comment: @Julio When you clone your own repository, you clone them locally in the path of your choosing. Try and clone one of them again, in a new path, and check if there is any huge file in there. If not, you can start working on it.

Comment: Thank you, I have just found out it was a package dowloaded long time ago without even using it. I went to the directory and run the command "git remote -v" and there was not git repository so I deleted it. Thank you again for your patience and help

Comment: @Julio Perfect, well done.